# Convert a (quite) simple XML file to JSON using Julia

Tags: json, xml, julia

I would like to convert [this XML file](https://github.com/stoni/ta-lib/blob/master/ta_func_api.xml) to JSON using Julia.

This is a quite simple XML file with tag / elements but without attributes.

I have found some online tools to do this but I would prefer
not to rely on such services and have my own Julia code for this.

LightXML might help for parsing

```
using LightXML
xdoc = parse_string(s_xml)
xroot = root(xdoc)
...
```

JSON.jl will be use to output JSON file

```
f = open("my.json", "w")
JSON.print(f, d)
close(f)
```

but I don't know how to traverse this XML tree to achieve such a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We came across exactly this problem a few days ago. We didn't find an already existing implementation in Julia, so we put a few functions together from scratch.

The basic solution was to traverse the XML using a recursive approach. Along the way we store the tags and elements in a series of nested `MultiDict` objects from the [DataStructures](https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl) package. And like you, we also use the LightXML package to parse the XML document when we begin.

Then, once we have the complete XML read in to our nested `MultiDict`, we begin to unpack the `MultiDict` (also using recursion) into a string with the appropriate formatting for JSON. This portion was a bit more tricky.

Our implementation is fairly simplistic; for example, we ignore the XML's attributes completely. But I think this kind of approach (i.e., recursion and nested multi-dictionaries) is probably not ridiculous and should get you on the right track.

**Edit:**

Our functions are wrapped up in a module. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/bcbi/XMLconvert.jl).

Comment: Is your code available (or could you make it available)?

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Sure, I'm cleaning it up a little and putting it on Github. I'll post the link in a bit.

Comment: @paulstey that will be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through an XML document using a simple recursive approach and [LightXML](https://github.com/JuliaLang/LightXML.jl). Here's a rough skeleton:

```
using LightXML

function xout(xelement, mode)
    if mode == 1
        println("<",name(xelement), ">")
    else
        println("\t{", name(xelement), "}\t", content(xelement))
    end
end

function parse_node(c)
    e = XMLElement(c)
    if length(collect(child_elements(e))) > 0
        xout(e, 1)
        for child in child_elements(e)
            parse_node(child)
        end
    else
        xout(e, 0)
    end
end

xdoc = parse_string(rawxml)
xroot = root(doc)

for c in child_elements(xroot)
    parse_node(c)
end
```

which for your file gives something like this:

```
<FinancialFunction>
    {Abbreviation}  ACOS
    {CamelCaseName} Acos
    {ShortDescription}  Vector Trigonometric ACos
    {GroupId}   Math Transform
<RequiredInputArguments>
<RequiredInputArgument>
    {Type}  Double Array
    {Name}  inReal
<OutputArguments>
<OutputArgument>
    {Type}  Double Array
    {Name}  outReal
<Flags>
    {Flag}  Line
```

Of course, the fun has only just begun! You've got to distinguish those different `<Type>` and `<Name>` tags for different elements, etc.. Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't look a JSON file

Comment: @FemtoTrader you asked "but I don't know how to traverse this XML tree to achieve such a task.".